# For a module that contains errors, can ghci process its import declarations only?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is it possible to have ghci (or cabal repl) load only the imports of a module?

If I load a module (from source) that contains some error, then the ghci session has the scope of the last module that was loaded successfully (?).

But to debug the current module, I want to be in its scope (i.e., have all its imports available).

Comment: Lucky for you a very similar question was asked the other day, although I can see why it would be hard to find it in search.  I've marked it as duplicate since the desired outcome is essentially the same and you can achieve what you want to do with the flag shown.

Comment: thanks, that was quick and helpful.